# wp_link_pages()

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Есть код, альтернатива `wp_link_pages` на **wordpres**, для вывода ссылок навигации по страницам, для многостраничных постов. Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить атрибут `class="page-link"` к ссылкам? Надо чтобы так было, пример: `<a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>`

```
function kama_link_pages(){
$text_num_page   = '';
$num_pages       = 10;
$stepLink        = 10;
$dotright_text   = '…';
$dotright_text2  = '…';
$backtext        = '« назад';
$nexttext        = 'вперед »';
$first_page_text = '« к началу';
$last_page_text  = 'в конец »';

global $page, $numpages;

$paged    = (int) $page;
$max_page = $numpages;

if( $max_page <= 1 )
    return false;

if( empty($paged) || $paged == 0) $paged = 1;

$pages_to_show         = intval($num_pages);
$pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show-1;

$half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
$half_page_end   = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);

$start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;
$end_page   = $paged + $half_page_end;

if( $start_page <= 0)
    $start_page = 1;

if( ($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1 )
    $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;

if( $end_page > $max_page ){
    $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    $end_page   = (int) $max_page;
}

if( $start_page <= 0 ) $start_page = 1;

$out = '<div class="wp-pagenavi">'. "\n";

    if( $text_num_page ){
        $text_num_page = preg_replace ('!{current}|{last}!', '%s', $text_num_page );
        $out .= sprintf ("<span class='pages'>$text_num_page</span>", $paged,$max_page );
    }

    if( $backtext && $paged != 1 )
        $out.= _wp_link_page($paged-1) . $backtext .'</a>';

    if( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page ) {
        $out .= _wp_link_page(1) . ( $first_page_text ?: 1 ) .'</a>';
        if( $dotright_text && $start_page != 2 )
            $out.= '<span class="extend">'. $dotright_text .'</span>';
    }

    for( $i = $start_page; $i <= $end_page; $i++ ){
        if( $i == $paged ) 
            $out .= '<span class="current">'. $i .'</span>';
        else
            $out .= _wp_link_page($i) . $i .'</a>';

    }

    if( $stepLink && $end_page < $max_page ){
        for( $i=$end_page+1; $i<=$max_page; $i++ ){
            if( $i % $stepLink == 0 && $i !== $num_pages ){
                if( ++$dd == 1 )
                    $out.= '<span class="extend">'. $dotright_text2 .'</span>';
                $out .= _wp_link_page($i) . $i .'</a>';
            }
        }
    }

    if( $end_page < $max_page ) {
        if( $dotright_text && $end_page != ($max_page-1) )
            $out.= '<span class="extend">'. $dotright_text2 .'</span>';
        $out .= _wp_link_page($max_page) . ( $last_page_text ?: $max_page ) .'</a>';
    }

    if( $nexttext && $paged != $end_page )
        $out .= _wp_link_page($paged+1) . $nexttext .'</a>';
$out .= '</div>';
return $out;
```

}

Comment: А чего бы у автора на его сайте не спросить?)

Comment: спросила, тишина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставьте такую строчку перед `return $out;`:

```
$out = str_replace( '<a', '<a class="page-link"', $out );
```

Comment: Всё работает ))), спасибо огромное!